# Equivalent of var in Visual Basic to use in For Each Loop

Tags: c#, vb.net

I need to run some code in Visual Basic that is the equivalent to this in C#:

```
for(var item in removeRows)
{
   two.ImportRow(item);
}
```

I know that the closest you can come to declaring "var" in VB is basically

```
Dim something =
```

However, how would you do this in a foreach loop?

Comment: Just FYI `Dim something` isn't really the same as `var` - it's more "leaving off the `As DataType` in a `Dim` statement" that's more like `var`.  It's the same with `For Each` - its more a matter of just not including the specifier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would just use:

```
For Each item In removeRows
    two.ImportRow(item)
Next
```

The `As datatype` specification in VB is optional.  See [For Each](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx) documentation for details.

Comment: Doing that I get the error "'item' not declared. It may be inaccesible due to it's protection level"

Comment: @NealR hrm... you shouldn't get that, using the code as above.  How is "removeRows" declared/defined?

Comment: @NealR What version are you using?

Comment: We are using .net 4.0. Declaring the "item As Object" solved the problem.

Comment: @NealR Try with `Option Infer On`, then you can omit the `As Object`

Answer (score 4):

With Option Infer On, you can leave off the "As ..." and the type will be inferred.
With Option Infer Off, if you leave off the type, the "Object" type will be assumed.

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned the As Type is option IF you have option infer on. I suspect your project has option infer turned off (which was the default when importing existing projects started in .Net 2.0). Turn Option Infer On at the top of the project file or in the project's Compile settings.

```
Option Infer On
'' This works:
For Each item In removeRows
   two.ImportRow(item)
Next

Option Infer Off
'' Requires:
For Each item As DataRow In removeRows
   '' I'm assuming the strong type here. Object will work with Option Strict Off
   two.ImportRow(item)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    For Each item As Object in removerows
       two.ImportRow(item)
    Next
```

Omitting the type in VB.NET (VB9) will implicitly type the variable.

Answer (score 0):

In the For Each documentation it is written that the [As Type is optional](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx).

So

```
For Each row in removeRows
...
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try (With `Object`), type is optional

```
For Each item As Object In removeRows
    two.ImportRow(item)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
   Dim siteName As String
   Dim singleChar As Char
   siteName = "HTTP://NET-INFORMATIONS.COM"
   For Each singlechar In siteName
        two.ImportRow(singleChar);
   Next
```

- http://vb.net-informations.com/programflow/vb.vb.net_for_each_loop.htm

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the "as" in vb:

```
For Each p  In Process.GetProcesses()
    Debug.WriteLine(p.ProcessName)
Next
```